# How To Export Compiled Protobuf to Static Library C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-c

I want to make a static library containing .cc and .h files that are generated from protoc compiler to link with it from other project, I'm using C++

Comment: What are you using to compile (cmake, bazel, ...) ? Could you give us some code that you have ?

Comment: I'm using protoc which is compiled from CMake and use this line `protoc --cpp_out=. test.proto` to generate .cc and .h files, i want to put this two files in one dll [c++]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using protoc manually you can let CMake compile the proto files. To do so you will have CMakeLists.txt in the same folder as you proto files (I use a separate folder called proto here). and this CMakeLists.txt will look like:

```
# Proto files
set(proto
    test.proto
    # maybe others
)

# Generated sources
set(proto_srcs
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto/test.pb.cc
    # maybe others
)

# Generated headers
set(proto_hdrs
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto/test.pb.h
    # maybe others
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${proto_srcs} ${proto_hdrs}
    COMMAND protoc
    ARGS --cpp_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto
        -I ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/proto
        ${proto} 
    DEPENDS ${proto}
)

add_library(protos
    ${proto_srcs}
    ${proto_hdrs}
)
target_link_libraries(protos
    libprotobuf
)
```

So as you can see you need to specify the proto files that you want to compile (first `set`). Then you need the specify the name of the generated cc and h file (second and third `set`). And then we use the custom command to generate automatically what you have been doing manually with protoc.

Finally, we create a `libprotos.a` (static library) file called protos_lib.a with the `add_library` and link the protobuf dependency with `target_link_libraries`.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank You, i have no experience with CMake, 
as i understand i should make cmakefile.txt with this above code and then run cmake to build ?
should i replace any parameters in this file?
like {CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} 
what about additional include that used from .h file ?

Comment: this is my output of compiling protobuf project from binary [ https://ibb.co/1dSqJ4J ]

Comment: i did it but there is a linker error,
the exe dosen't build

Comment: @PeterBoshra Try to update your question with what you tried (folder architecture, ...) and what error it displays.